# Grep: поиск разницы файлов и вывод с новой строки

Tags: bash, grep

Здравствуйте. Имеются два файла (`file1.txt` и `file2.txt`), их содержание следующее, file1:

```
a  
b  
c  
d
```

file2:

```
a  
b  
x  
z
```

Пишу скрипт, чтобы в третий файл выводилась разница **с новой строки:**

> grep -F -v -f file2.txt file1.txt >> diff.txt

Но вывод получается только "cd", т.е. в одну строку.
Буду благодарен за помощь!

UPDATE: Проблема решилась путем добавления | awk '{sub(/$/,"\r");print}'

Comment: А что такое "разница" ? и почему собственно grep, для поиска отличий в файлах существует утилита `diff`

Comment: В данном случае разница - это то что есть только в первом файле

Comment: а файлы  file2.txt file1.txt в какой ОС созданы?

Comment: просто добавь доп символ `grep -F -v -f file2.txt file1.txt  | awk '{print $0,"\n"}' >> diff.txt`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor файлы созданы в Windows. С добавлением awk в выводе просто добавляются пробелы, т.е. "c d "

Comment: @SeniorPomidor проблема решилась немного по другому, но все равно спасибо!

Comment: `diff -u file2 file1 | grep ^\+`. Как-то так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема в том, что [символ окончания строки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) отличается в разных ОС. поэтому, windows покажет вам символы с новой строки, а для Unix они будут отличаться. 
Из за этого вы не видите в linux символы с новой строки. Это можно решить, добавив символы `\r\n`

```
grep -F -v -f file2.txt file1.txt | awk '{print $0,"\r\n"}' >> diff.txt
```

Comment: Спасибо! А в чем принципиальное отличие '{print $0,"\r\n"}' от '{sub(/$/,"\r");print}' ?

Comment: sub конвертирует Windows/DOS символы (CRLF) на Unix (LF). твой вариант лучше, чем мой. но будут проблемы, если этот файл потом открыть в windows. тогда будет одна длинная строка без переноса